# Listener for another thread

Tags: java, android, events

I have an application that has a GUI and TCP server. The TCP server is running in a different thread and when it receives a certain packet, it should start playing a video file (from MediaPlayer object). The problem is that as a GUI component, the video may be displayed only if invoked from the main thread. I added a listener class to the main class:

```
Class RequestListener implements NBRequestListener{  /* NBRequestListener is the interface */
public void onRequestArrived(String request) {
processRequest(request); /* This method will run the video */
}
```

I created a listener in the main thread and set it as a listener in the server:

```
RequestListener listener = new RequestListener();
server.setRequestListener(listener);
```

The code in the server is:

```
public void setRequestListener(_listener) {
listener = _listener; } /* listener is defined as RequestListener */
```

and the invocation of the event (in the server) is simply:

```
listener.onRequestArrived(input_from_client);
```

But the listener method is invoked in the server thread and not in the main thread and therefore I get exception: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.  Could you please help pointing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to solve this one, here's two:

1. Use a Handler in your Activity. For example, when you get a notification from your background thread, that the video needs to be played, you send a message to your Activity's handler. Code in your custom Handler gets to run on the UI thread. Here's a tutorial (from the many) http://www.helloandroid.com/taxonomy/term/43
2. When the background thread gets the packet, broadcast an Intent (startBroadcast() on the context class). Register a receiver for this broadcast in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to have the consumer thread (here, your main thread) wait on a semaphore or a lock, and the producer thread (here, the server thread) release the semaphore or the lock when the resource is available (i.e. when the input from the client has been received).

Have a look at Lock and Semaphore in the `java.util.concurrent` and `java.util.concurrent.locks` packages.

Comment: Thanks, but since my main thread is the GUI thread, won't it cause that no GUI component will appear (since the thread is locked) ?

Answer (score 0):

Many UI require only one thread (the "event" thread) to perform operation on the UI state. This is to prevent concurrency and consistency problems.

When you call a method from another thread, you break this rule. Typically a good solution is to add an event to the event queue that will be executed in the context of the event thread.

In swing it is something like this :

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    //Your UI code to be run in the context of the event thread.
    //In your case linking the video.
  }
});
```

As you said, you should not block the UI thread, or it will block it.